# Tabla Unicode PHP

Tags: php, php7

3.11 :

- Como Mejora (Avanzada), has que la tabla anterior se pueda mostrar por paginada.
  De modo que cada pantalla se muestren 500 códigos y unos enlaces permitan pasar a la siguiente pagina.
- Ejemplo de salida (Si pulsamos dos veces al enlace de avance de pagina) :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema esta en que intento realizar dos botones de retrocesos y siguiente pero no me hace la haciendo de sumar la variable a 100 ya que 100 x 10 es 1000 500 para el contandor incrementado y 500 para los caracteres

```
<?php

// funciones

function uni($pagina = 1, $columnas = 10, $filas = 100, $uni = 50000) {
    $contador=1;
    $metete="&#";
    $salida_funcion = '
<table border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>';

    for ($j = 1; $j <= $columnas; $j++) { 
        if ($j%2 == 1) {
            $salida_funcion .= '
      <th id="color">Codigo</th>';
            
        }elseif ($j%2 == 0) {
            $salida_funcion .= '
      <th>Valor</th>';       
        }

    }
    $salida_funcion .= '
    </tr>';

    for ($i=1; $i <= $filas; $i++) { 
        
        for ($j=1; $j <= $columnas && $contador <= $uni ; $j++,$contador++) {
            
            $letra = $metete.$contador;
            $aux = $contador;# *
            if ($j%2 == 1) {
                $salida_funcion .= '<th>'.$contador.'</th>';
                $contador--;
            
            }elseif ($j%2 == 0) {
                $salida_funcion .= '<th>'.$letra.'</th>';

            }
        }

        $salida_funcion .= '
    </tr>';
    }

        $salida_funcion .= '
  </tbody>
</table>';
    return $salida_funcion;
}

// algoritmo

$columnas = 10; 
$filas = 100;
$letra = 65;
$uni = 50000;
$total_paginas = $uni / ($filas * $columnas / 2);


if (isset($_GET['pagina'])) {     
    $pagina = $_GET['pagina']; 
} else {     
    $pagina = 1; 
}

if ($pagina > 0 and $pagina <= $total_paginas) {
    if ($pagina > 1) {         
        $pos = $pagina - 1;     
    } else {         
        $pos = 1;     
    }
    if ($pagina < $total_paginas) {         
        $next = $pagina + 1;     
    } else {         
        $next = $total_paginas;     
    }
} else {     // cancelamos la salida     
    die('<h1>Lo siento, la página está fuera del rango permitido. Debe estar entre 1 y '.$total_paginas.'</h1>'); 
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>UNICODE</title>
    <link href="uni.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
    <center>
    <table id="titulo">
      <tr>
        <td><form method="get" action="">
                <input type="hidden" name="pagina" value="<?php echo $pos ?>" />
                <input type="submit" id="menu" value="<"/>
            </form>
        </td>
        <td>
          <h1 >Pagina <?php echo $pagina ?></h1>
        </td>
        <td>
          <form method="get" action="">
            <input type="hidden" name="pagina" value="<?php echo $next ?>" />
            <input type="submit" id="menu1" value=">"/>
          </form>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <br/>
    <?php echo uni($pagina, $columnas, $filas, $uni); ?>
    </center>
</body>
</html>
```

La tabla del anterior ejercicio me salía los 50000 caracteres de Unicode pero ahora ya me funciona la tabla solo falta configurar esos botones

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas gracias por la ayuda de antemano

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema esta en la variable contador, que no se recalculaba repitiendo siempre la misma posición del elemento inicial, por lo tanto siempre salia la primera página:

```php
$contador = 1;
```

La manera correcta de calcular el inicio del contador seria esta:

```php
if($pagina>1) {
    $contador = (($pagina-1) * ($columnas/2) * $filas) + 1;
} else {
    $contador = $pagina;
}
```

**Explicación de la fórmula:**

```
($pagina-1) * ($columnas/2) * $filas) + 1
```

**donde:**

- **($pagina-1)**: es el número de página actual al cual le restamos 1, pues ya sabemos que, dado el condicional, al menos valdrá 2.
- **($columnas/2)**: **$columnas** es el total de columnas que el OP desea usar en la tabla, **que debe ser par** porque se divide en pares de código-valor en los siguentes bucles de la función, y por eso dividimos el total de columnas por 2, pues solo una de ellas contiene elementos de la tabla unicode, y el contador solo cuenta esos elementos.
- **$filas** es la cantidad de filas a mostrar en cada página
- **+ 1** es para conseguir que el contador, a partir de la página 1, empiece en el siguiente elemento calculado en el resto de esta fórmula, pues aún pertenece a la página anterior.

Comment: muchas gracias por tu ayuda te dejo un enlace de mi hosting con el ejericio saludos. https://javiergraya.000webhostapp.com/uni.php?pagina=1

Comment: de nada, jeje, me alegro que ya lo hayas terminado, espero que te pongan buena nota :-)  (y lo más importante, que hayas aprendido las cosas básicas que estuvimos mirando para que los próximos desarrollos que tengas que hacer no sean tan liosos y separes mejor las cosas)

Comment: si aprendí mucho

Comment: Muuy buena @masterguru